# Can MATLAB interpret different region of an acoustic wave diagram?

Tags: function, matlab, graph

I am trying to construct this process:
[image]

in MATLAB. The wave would reflect and refract many times in between these two materials. The equation given in the picture is a way to calculate the speed and pressure/stress of the material at different regions (A is the region below the "reflected" line, B is the region below the "transmitted" line, etc). I don't want to draw the line manually and calculate manually, but I have never heard of a matlab function that can draw the acoustic wave line for me. Is there such a tool in MATLAB, and a way to automate the calculation of speed and stress/pressure of each region?